# CRASH ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID iOS17 - Anyone seen this?

Tags: crash, ios17, nsexception, google-analytics-sdk

Title says it all. Been calling this for 10 years. Ran on iOS17 today for the first time and get an uncaught NSException that takes the app down.

GoogleAnalytics 3.21 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:48): Uncaught exception: +[ACTConversionIDReporter referrerComponentsForReferrerKeyWithSuffix:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100c7ef50

Have Googled and zero results for 'ACTConversionIDReporter'.  Yes I can catch the exception, but hoping someone has seen this. Thanks!

I have updated every Pod in my project. I have added various linker flags suggested by other searches for somewhat similar issues. I have prayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use -ld64 in your xcode project. The new linker problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).